# TailFile Processor- Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Tailfile processor to fetch logs from a cluster(3 nodes) scheduled to run every minute. The log file name changes for every hour
I was confused on which Tailing mode should I use . If I use Single File it is not fetching the new file generated after 1 hour. If I use the multifile, It is fetching the file after 3rd minute of file name change which is increasing the size of the file. what should be the rolling filename for my file and which mode should I use.
Could you please let me know. Thank you

Myfilename:
retrieve-11.log (generated at 11:00)- this is removed but single file mode still checks for this file
after 1 hour retrieve-12.log (generated at 12:00)

My Processor Confuguration:

Tailing mode: Multiple Files

File(s) to Tail: retrieve-${now():format("HH")}.log

Rolling Filename Pattern: ${filename}.*.log

Base Directory: /ext/logs

Initial Start Position: Beginning of File

State Location: Local

Recursive lookup: false

Lookup Frequency: 10 minutes

Maximum age: 24 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you aren't really doing normal log file rolling. That would be, for example, where you write to `logfile.log` then after 1 day, you move `logfile.log` to be `logfile.log.1` and then write new logs to a new, empty `logfile.log`.

Instead, it sounds like you are just writing logs to a different file based on the hour. I assume this means you overwrite each file every 24h?

So something like this might work?

[image: config]

EDIT:

So given that you are doing the following:

```
At 10:00, `retrieve-10.log` is created. Logs are written here.
At 11:00, `retrieve-11.log` is created. Logs are now written here.
At 11:10, `retrieve-10.log` is moved.

TailFile is only run every 10 minutes.
```

Then targeting a file based on the hour won't work. At 10:00, your tailFile **only** reads `retrieve-10.log`. At 11:00 your tailFile **only** reads `retrieve-11.log`. So worst case, you miss 10 minuts of logs between 10:50 and 11:00.

Given that another process is cleaning up the old files, there isn't going to be a back log of old files to worry about. So it sounds like there's no need to set the hour specifically.

```
tailing mode: multiple files
files to tail: /path/retrieve-*.log
```

With this, at 10:00, tailFile tails `retrieve-9.log` and `retrieve-10.log`. At 10:10, `retrieve-9.log` is removed and it tails `retrieve-10.log`. At 11:00 it tails `retrieve-10.log` and `retrieve-11.log`. At 11:10, `retrieve-10.log` is removed and it tails `retrieve-11.log`. Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not overwriting the file. for every hour new log file will be generated and previous file will be moved to another folder.
for example if the log file is generated at 10:00AM the file name will be retrieve-10, in the next hour at 11:10AM , retrieve-10 will be moved and at 11:00  retrieve-11 will be generated.

Comment: Also I changed the tailfile processor to run at every 10 minutes due to some memory issues at other end.
So once retrieve-10 is tailed at 10:50, the processor directly picking retrieve-11 file at 11:00 now and ignoring retrieve-10 file.

Comment: The safest option would be to move to a proper log file rolling technique. If that's not possible, then just do; `tailing mode: multiple files` and `files to tail: /path/retrieve-*.log` - if another process is already cleaning up the old files, then you don't need to target a specific hours file with the `now()` call - this is why you can't pick up the old file in the last run before its deleted.